# Implementing an existing C Code:: Blocks project as a DLL

Tags: c, dll, codeblocks

I have a C::B project which evaluates a mathematical expression using a stack Linked List, with several source files and header files. I need to export this project to a Dynamically Linked Library.
I already know how to create a DLL on C::B, however, I have no idea how to export an existing project as a DLL.

How can this be done?

Comment: If you know how to create a dll, then start with an empty one and add the files manually, wouldn't that work?

Comment: I suggest trying what @SelçukCihan suggested, and coming back if you have any problems with that. For now, I'm going to vote to close this question as "too broad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change how your project is exported by going to the project properties (project->properties) then going to the tab build targets. Here you will see all build targets of your current project. You'll notice this menu has a field named "type". If you change this field to "Dynamic Library" your project will compile as a .dll on windows, or as a .so on Linux.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem! So in order to use this in my project, I have to link it via linker, rather than import it like I used to do with header files, am i correct?

Comment: Yes, you specify the dynamic library as library in the build options of your project, and specify the path to the library as linker path. You should also set the include path to wherever your header files are located, so the compiler can find them.